# Is -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections and --gc-sections not working?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I want to remove unused functions from code while compiling. Then I write some code (main.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *get1();

int main()
{
    puts( get1() );
}
```

and getall.c:

```
const char *get1()
{
    return "s97symmqdn-1";
}


const char *get2()
{
    return "s97symmqdn-2";
}

const char *get3()
{
    return "s97symmqdn-3";
}
```

Makefile

```
test1   :
        rm -f a.out *.o *.a
        gcc -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -c main.c getall.c
        ar cr libgetall.a getall.o
        gcc -Wl,--gc-sections main.o -L. -lgetall
```

After run `make test1 && objdump --sym a.out | grep get` , I only find the next 2 lines output:

```
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000              getall.c
0000000000400535 g     F .text  000000000000000b              get1
```

I guess the `get2` and `get3` was removed. But when I open the a.out by vim, I found `s97symmqdn-1 s97symmqdn-2 s97symmqdn-3` exists. 
Is the function `get2` `get3` removed really ? How I can remove the symbol `s97symmqdn-2 s97symmqdn-3` ? Thank you for your reply.
My system is centos7 and gcc version is 4.8.5

Comment: You should probably compile with `-O1` or higher.

Comment: I used -O1， but it still exists s97symmqdn-2 s97symmqdn-3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compilation options `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` and linkage option `--gc-sections`
are working correctly in your example. Your static library is superfluous, so it can
be simplified to:

```
$ gcc -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -c main.c getall.c
$ gcc -Wl,--gc-sections main.o getall.o -Wl,-Map=mapfile
```

in which I'm also asking for the linker's mapfile.

The unused functions `get2` and `get3` are absent from the executable:

```
$ nm a.out | grep get
0000000000000657 T get1
```

and the mapfile shows that the unused function-sections `.text.get2` and `.text.get3` in which `get2` and `get3` are
respectively defined were discarded in the linkage:

**mapfile (1)**

```
...
Discarded input sections
...
 .text.get2     0x0000000000000000        0xd getall.o
 .text.get3     0x0000000000000000        0xd getall.o
...
```

Nevertheless, as you found, all three of the string literals `"s97symmqdn-(1|2|3)"`
are in the program:

```
$ strings a.out | egrep 's97symmqdn-(1|2|3)'
s97symmqdn-1
s97symmqdn-2
s97symmqdn-3
```

That is because `-fdata-sections` applies just to the same data objects that
[`__attribute__ ((__section__("name")))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) applies to<sup>1</sup>, i.e. to the definitions
of *variables* that have [static storage duration](http://iso-9899.info/wiki/Storage_Duration). It is not applied to anonymous string literals like your
`"s97symmqdn-(1|2|3)"`. They are all just placed in the `.rodata` section as usual,
and there we find them:

```
$ objdump -s -j .rodata a.out

a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .rodata:
 06ed 73393773 796d6d71 646e2d31 00733937  s97symmqdn-1.s97
 06fd 73796d6d 71646e2d 32007339 3773796d  symmqdn-2.s97sym
 070d 6d71646e 2d3300                      mqdn-3.
```

`--gc-sections` does not allow the linker to discard `.rodata` from the program
because it is not an unused section: it contains `"s97symmqdn-1"`, referenced
in the program by `get1` as well as the unreferenced strings `"s97symmqdn-2"`
and `"s97symmqdn-3"`

**Fix**

To get these three string literals separated into distinct data sections, you
need to assign them to distinct named objects, e.g.

**getcall.c (2)**

```
const char *get1()
{
    static const char s[] = "s97symmqdn-1";
    return s;
}


const char *get2()
{
    static const char s[] = "s97symmqdn-2";
    return s;
}

const char *get3()
{
    static const char s[] = "s97symmqdn-3";
    return s;
}
```

If we recompile and relink with that change, we see:

**mapfile (2)**

```
...
Discarded input sections
...
 .text.get2     0x0000000000000000        0xd getall.o
 .text.get3     0x0000000000000000        0xd getall.o
 .rodata.s.1797
                0x0000000000000000        0xd getall.o
 .rodata.s.1800
                0x0000000000000000        0xd getall.o
...
```

Now there are two new discarded data-sections, which contain
the two string literals we don't need, as we can see in the object file:

```
$ objdump -s -j .rodata.s.1797 getall.o

getall.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .rodata.s.1797:
 0000 73393773 796d6d71 646e2d32 00        s97symmqdn-2.
```

and:

```
$ objdump -s -j .rodata.s.1800 getall.o

getall.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .rodata.s.1800:
 0000 73393773 796d6d71 646e2d33 00        s97symmqdn-3.
```

Only the referenced string `"s97symmqdn-1"` now appears anywhere in the program:

```
$ strings a.out | egrep 's97symmqdn-(1|2|3)'
s97symmqdn-1
```

and it is the only string in the program's `.rodata`:

```
$ objdump -s -j .rodata a.out

a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .rodata:
 06f0 73393773 796d6d71 646e2d31 00        s97symmqdn-1.
```

---

[1] Likewise, `-function-sections` has the same effect as qualifying the
definition of every function `foo` with `__attribute__ ((__section__(".text.foo")))`

Comment: Isn't it a deficiency? Why it was implemented this way? I would expect these literals to go away too... Another observation -- if you use __func__/__PRETTY_FUNC__/etc instead of literals -- it gets discarded. What is the mechanism that ensures that?

Comment: One more observation: `-flto` is another way to address OP's problem (doesn't even need `-fdata-sections`)